# funcion includes ts y js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy trabajando Vue y tengo el siguiente problema con TS:

```js
 filterByStatus({ commit, state }, status) {
      const results = state.characters.filter((character) => {
        return character.status.includes(status);
      });

 return character.status.includes(status);
  });
```

En la línea **`return`** dice que status no existe en el tipo **`never`**,
ahora si el código es ejecutado en js si funciona
mi pregunta real es ¿cuál es el error al trabajarlo con TS?

Answer (score 0):

resulta que js dara error durante la ejecucion a diferencia de typeScript que me indicara el error de inmediato.

el codigo final quedo asi:

```
filterByStatus({ commit, state }, status) {
      const results = state.characters.filter((character: any) => {
        return character.status.includes(status);
      });
```

solo habia que agregar la palabra any a character